# multiple domains, one static IP address and latency

Tags: ip-address, latency, static-ip, domain

how is latency affected when multiple domains are using one single static IP address ? The scenario is in shared web-hosting

By latency meaning the DNS lookup the client has to do. As far as I understand it, the browser would hit the root servers to try to figure out the IP Address and it belongs where and then when it comes to the correct server, it probably looks up some sort of table to determine which site names much and show that site as such via browser to the user.

Is my understanding correct or backwards or what ?

Answer (score 4):

Your understanding is not correct. The time for an A or CNAME record query does not depend, in any way, on how many other A or CNAME records might also point to the same IP address.

The hosting company may not have enough bandwidth (or CPU, or RAM, etc) to support good response times for all clients if one of the clients is particularly popular, but that is an entirely separate issue from your question.

You should definitely spend some time on self-study, if your job depends on understanding these matters.

- http://www.quackit.com/how-websites-work/how-dns-works.cfm
- http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Unix-and-Internet-Fundamentals-HOWTO/internet.html
- http://www.howstuffworks.com/dns.htm